# How can I find the directions to this LEGO bag?

Tags: sets

I have a LEGO bag unopened but we lost the directions!  Can someone help?  I think it's Minecraft.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you identify it. Can you post a picture or a link to a picture?

Answer (score 2):

You can look for lego instructions at a couple of websites. Here are the links.

http://letsbuilditagain.com/

http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-instructions

http://lego.brickinstructions.com/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the 3rd party sites listed by Samuel L, LEGO also publish most of their building instructions on their site - you can search by set number, theme or year. Currently [searching for Minecraft](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&theme=10000-20231) turns up 18 sets.

Comment: Agreed. You have a very good point! XD